# Moving my for loop into a different method and connecting it to main Java

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I'm making a program using Java that calculates the sum of the numbers entered; I figured this part out. However, I want to move the for loop into a different method called "Sum", but I keep getting errors and I don't know what to do.

Here is the code thats only in the Main method (it works perfectly fine):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class testing {
   public static void main(String args[]){
      System.out.println("Enter the size of the array: ");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      int size = in.nextInt();
      int myArray[] = new int [size];
      int sum = 0;
      System.out.println("Enter the elements of the array one by one: ");

      for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
         myArray[i] = in.nextInt();
         sum = sum + myArray[i];
      }
      System.out.println("Sum of the elements of the array: "+ sum);
   }
}
```

However, when I move the for loop into the method known as print, I get a bunch of errors:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MPA4 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Enter the size of the array: ");
              Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
              int size = in.nextInt();
              int myArray[] = new int [size];
              int sum = 0;
              System.out.println("Enter the elements of the array one by one: ");
            }
             print(sum);
    }
        public static void print (double []sum){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int myArray[] = new int [size];
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
                 myArray[i] = in.nextInt();
                 sum = sum + myArray[i];
        }
            System.out.println("Sum of the elements of the array: "+ sum);
    }
}
```

Here are all the errors underlined in red:
[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it as below and it is working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MP4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the size of the array: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = in.nextInt();
    int myArray[] = new int[size];
    System.out.println("Enter the elements of the array one by one: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        myArray[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    print(myArray, size);
}

public static void print(int[] myArray, int size) {
    int sum = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        sum = sum + myArray[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of the elements of the array: " + sum);
}
}
```